# Should I mention a cancelled research summer internship in my document?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application, cv, research-undergraduate, internship

I got the admission from Mitacs Globalink Research Internship last year, a research internship initiative in Canada, but it was cancelled due to Covid19. Now I am applying for my Master program in a different major (My research program is physics but I am applying for Computer Science Program), should I mention it in my application document (like CV & Statement .etc)? If it is feasible, how to describe it properly?

PS: I contacted my instructor after the cancellation if it was possible to conduct it in a remote mode, but after the consideration he rejected it because of the difficulty of doing research remotely. So I have not done anything about the program

Many other people must have encountered the same cancellation in various programs, and some of my peers in the program have the same questions. I hope to hear a good instruction on the issue, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cancelled Summer Program due to COVID-19](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/147165/cancelled-summer-program-due-to-covid-19)

Answer (score 3):

You were still awarded a competitive internship.  Just indicate

- Mitacs Globalink Research Internship at such-and-such (not held because of COVID)

or something to that effect.

Comment: @Buffy Mitacs Globalinks is not a “program” in the academic sense so you’re not “admitted” to it.  It’s a program in the sense that Mitacs funds some internships and runs the process of selecting the interns in partnership with hosts.